# Bean reflection

Tags: java

Is there a way to copy objects that contain other objects as long as they have the same getter and setter method names? For instance I'm getting objects back from a web service and most of the objects contain other objects. Most go at least 5 layers deep where they branch off with other objects.

I want to set the objects returned to my own objects of the same name with the same getter and setter method names. My problem is I can't guarantee the web service won't change meaning I can't just use the objects generated from the wsdl.

I'm starting to look into BeanUtils but it doesn't seem to recursively look through objects. Any advice or a point in the right direction would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [DOZER](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/)

> Dozer is a Java Bean to Java Bean mapper that recursively copies data
>   from one object to another. Typically, these Java Beans will be of
>   different complex types.